# how to extract hour from time in a string and populate an empty dictionary?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a list (example shown below). How do I extract the hour from `list1[0]` and use it as a key in two dictionaries `count_by_hour` and 'comments_by_hour'? From the replies I received, I was able to get count_by_hour, but how do I get to total comments for every hour mentioned?
Here is some code:

```py
count_by_hour = {}
comments_by_hour = {}

counts_by_hour will come from index[0] while number of comments(num_comments) come from index[1]

list1 = [['8/16/2016 9:55', 6], ['11/22/2015 13:43', 29], ['5/2/2016 10:14', 1],
    ['8/2/2016 14:20', 3], ['10/15/2015 16:38', 17], ['9/26/2015 23:23', 1],
    ['4/22/2016 12:24', 4], ['11/16/2015 9:22', 1], ['2/24/2016 17:57', 1], 
    ['6/4/2016 17:17', 2]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution with relevant comments

```py
dict1 = []

list1 = [['8/16/2016 9:55', 6], ['11/22/2015 13:43', 29], ['5/2/2016 10:14', 1],
    ['8/2/2016 14:20', 3], ['10/15/2015 16:38', 17], ['9/26/2015 23:23', 1],
    ['4/22/2016 12:24', 4], ['11/16/2015 9:22', 1], ['2/24/2016 17:57', 1], 
    ['6/4/2016 17:17', 2]]

for each in list1:
  if each[0].split(':')[0][-2] == " ": #split by : to get second last char and check if >9
    dict1.append(each[0].split(':')[0][-1:]) # if hour is <9 take last char which is hour
  else:
    dict1.append(each[0].split(':')[0][-2:]) else take last 2 chars
```

Answer (score 0):

So if everything follows the same format you can split the strings:

for example:

```
dict1 = {}

s = '8/16/2016 9:55'
p = s.split(" ") # -> ['8/16/2016', '9:55']

hour, mins = p[1].split(":") # -> ['9', '55']

dict1[hour] = # value
```

Answer (score 0):

You could match the hour with a [RegEx](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) such as `r"^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}\s(\d{1,2}):\d{2}$"` and then utilise the matched group, or you could convert the date and time to a python `datetime` using [strptime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) and then get the hour value of the datetime.

Answer (score 0):

3 ways:

First way:

```
import re

dt = '8/16/2016 9:55'
date_regex = r'\d+\/\d+\/\d{4} (?P<hours>\d+)\:\d+'
match = re.match(date_regex, dt)
print(match.group('hours'))
```

Second way:

```
dt = '8/16/2016 9:55'
date, time = dt.split(' ')
hours, minutes = time.split(':')
```

Third way:

```
from datetime import datetime

res = datetime.strptime('8/16/2016 9:55', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
print(res.time().hour)
```

Comment: I tried the third option:
    
for row in list1:
    date_time = row[0]
    res = datetime.strptime(date_time, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
print(res.time().hour)

output is:
ValueError: time data '8' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'

Comment: You can get such error only if you do next: `datetime.strptime('8', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')` and of course `strptime` can't parse such string

Answer (score 0):

if all timestamps are of same format you can handle it like below

```
from time import strptime

dict1 = {}
list1 = [['8/16/2016 9:55', 6], ['11/22/2015 13:43', 29], ['5/2/2016 10:14', 1],
    ['8/2/2016 14:20', 3], ['10/15/2015 16:38', 17], ['9/26/2015 23:23', 1],
    ['4/22/2016 12:24', 4], ['11/16/2015 9:22', 1], ['2/24/2016 17:57', 1], 
    ['6/4/2016 17:17', 2]]

for item in list1:
    dt_obj = strptime(item[0], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
    dict1[dt_obj.tm_hour] = item
```

Answer (score 0):

Python comprehensions are a great and clean way to solve more iterative problems. Comprehensions are idiomatic Python and are typically faster than writing a Python loop (as they are optimized and processed in C).

Also, most common problems, like parsing a date/time, can be solved using something from the standard library.  Here we want to use `strptime` from the `time` module (see answer above by [Prasanna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1210578/prasanna)).

In this case, we can make the dictionary using `strptime` and a dictionary comprension.

```
In [1]: list1 = [['8/16/2016 9:55', 6], ['11/22/2015 13:43', 29], ['5/2/2016 10:14', 1],
      : ['8/2/2016 14:20', 3], ['10/15/2015 16:38', 17], ['9/26/2015 23:23', 1],
      : ['4/22/2016 12:24', 4], ['11/16/2015 9:22', 1], ['2/24/2016 17:57', 1],
      : ['6/4/2016 17:17', 2]]

In [2]: from time import strptime

In [3]: hour_dict = {strptime(time, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M").tm_hour:val for time, val in list1}

In [4]: hour_dict
Out[5]: {9: 1, 13: 29, 10: 1, 14: 3, 16: 17, 23: 1, 12: 4, 17: 2}
}
```